# How to apply Window function to multiple columns in DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following DataFrame `df`:

```
Id   label   field1   field2
1    xxx     2        3
1    yyy     1        5
2    aaa     0        10
1    zzz     2        6
```

For each unique `Id` I want to know the `label` with highest `field1` and `field2`.

Expected result:

```
Id   labelField1   lableLield2
1    xxx           zzz
2    aaa           aaa
```

I know how to do it if I would only have `labelField1` or `labelField2`.
But I am not sure what is the best way to deal with both labels.

```
val w1 = Window.partitionBy($"Id").orderBy($"field1".desc)
val w2 = Window.partitionBy($"Id").orderBy($"field2".desc)

val myLabels = df.select("Id", "label", "field1", "field2")
                        .withColumn("rn", row_number.over(w1)).where($"rn" === 1)
                        .drop("rn")
                        .drop("field1")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `struct` and `max` inbuild functions to achieve your requirement as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.groupBy("Id")
    .agg(max(struct("field1", "label")).as("temp1"), max(struct("field2", "label")).as("temp2"))
    .select(col("Id"), col("temp1.label").as("labelField1"), col("temp2.label").as("labelField2"))
  .show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+---+-----------+-----------+
|Id |labelField1|labelField2|
+---+-----------+-----------+
|1  |xxx        |zzz        |
|2  |aaa        |aaa        |
+---+-----------+-----------+
```

**Note: In case of *tie* as in `field1` for *Id=1* there is *tie* between `xxx` and `zzz` so random will be chosen**